# Solving a recurrence related to tree counting

Tags: recurrence-relations

What I want is to count the number of binary trees on $n$ nodes, except when a node has only one child, I don't distinguish between left and right. So let $T_n$ be the number of such trees on $n$ nodes, we have

\begin{align*}
  T_n=\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}T_k\cdot T_{n-k-1}\right)-T_{n-1}.
\end{align*}

I am not sure how to solve this recurrence. If we proceed the same way as in counting normal binary trees (where left and right matters when there's a single child) using generating function $g(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty T_ns^n$ and squaring it, I get that

\begin{align*}
  g(s)=\frac{1+s-\sqrt{1-2s-3s^2}}{2s}.
\end{align*}

Calculating the series expansion around zero seems to give me what I want, but I cannot get this expression in the form of $\sum_nT_ns^n$ so the quantity $T_n$ comes out...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [A086246](http://oeis.org/A086246) in OEIS, but with the index shifted by $1$, and [A001006, the Motzkin numbers](http://oeis.org/A001006), with the index shifted by $1$ in the other direction. (That is, $T_{n+1}=M_n$, where $M_n$ is the $n$-th Motzkin number.) The latter reference yields the possibly simpler recurrence

$$T_{n+1}=\frac{2n+1}{n+2}T_n+\frac{3n-3}{n+2}T_{n-1}\;,$$

the asymptotic formula

$$T_n\sim 3^n\sqrt3\frac{1+\frac1{16n}}{(2n+3)\sqrt{(n+1)\pi}}\;,$$

and a wealth of references, formulas involving summations, and variant forms of the generating function, but there doesn’t seem to be a nice closed form.

Not so nice closed forms for the Motzkin numbers involving trinomial coefficients, hypergeometric functions, regularized hypergeometric functions and the gamma function, or Legendre polynomials can be found [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MotzkinNumber.html).

Answer (score 1):

Your trees are described by an empty tree or a root linked to a sequence of at most 2 non-empty trees, in symbols:
$$
\mathcal{T} 
  = \mathcal{E} 
       + \mathcal{Z} \times \mathfrak{S}_{\le 2}(\mathcal{T} - \mathcal{E})
$$
This directly gives the functional equation:
$$
T(z) = 1 + z (1 + (T(z) - 1) + (T(z) - 1)^2)
$$
This also gives:
$$
T(z) = \frac{1 - z - \sqrt{1 - 2 z - 3 z^2}}{2 z}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to mention that there is an implicit assumption in your problem that $T_0=T_1=1$. In this case your Z-transform is correct. Now the question is to invert the Z transform. This is pretty straightforward:
\begin{eqnarray}
g(s) &=& \frac{1}{2} - \left(\frac{\sqrt{1-2 s-3 s^2}-1}{2 s}\right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} - \left(\frac{\sqrt{(1+s)(1-3 s)}-1}{2 s} \right) \\
&=& \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n+1} F_{2,1}\left[\begin{array}{r} -\frac{1}{2} & -n-1 \\ \frac{1}{2} - n \end{array};-3\right] \cdot s^n
\end{eqnarray}
In the last line we multiplied the respective binomial expansions and then we computed the resulting convolution bu using the definition of the hypergeometric function. Therefore the result reads:
\begin{equation}
T_n = \frac{1}{2} \delta_{n,0} -\frac{1}{2} \binom{\frac{1}{2}}{n+1} F_{2,1}\left[\begin{array}{r} -\frac{1}{2} & -n-1 \\ \frac{1}{2} - n \end{array};-3\right] 
\end{equation}
Now the result can be further simplified using the theory of hypergeometric functions.